# Verify webelement using "@current_page" in watir

Tags: ruby, watir, verify, current-page

Step1 and Step2 take me back on "LandingPage". I want to verify the element using `@current_page`.
This is element is defined in "LandingPage.rb".

I have tried this, but no luck. Whats missing?

```
Step1
Step2

1. fail if not @current_page.(on(LandingPage.cart_box.present?))
2. fail if not @current_page.(on(LandingPage.cart_box)).present?
3. fail if not @current_page.(on(LandingPage.cart_box_element)).present?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `@current_page` is set in `Step1` or `Step2`, it will be an instance of `LandingPage`. You should not be calling the `on` method.

Depending on your goal, you can do either of the following:

```
@current_page.cart_box?
```

Or

```
@current_page.cart_box_element.visible?
```

Note that if you want the check to fail the test, you will need to use the result in your test framework's assertion library.